# Better to pass struct, or pointer to struct?

Tags: c, struct, embedded

I have a data struct, that will be read in a function.

I want the smallest memory, code size, and speed footprint possible. I'm working on AVR.

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t clu;
    uint16_t num;
    uint32_t cur_rel;
} FSAVEPOS;
```

Now, a function that stores file position into the struct:

```
// Approach 1
FSAVEPOS save_pos(const FFILE* file); // return value

// Approach 2
void save_pos(const FFILE* file, FSAVEPOS* pos); // modify reference
```

And a function that reverses this (FFILE object is modified):

```
// Approach 1
void restore_pos(FFILE* file, const FSAVEPOS pos); // pass by value

// Approach 2
void restore_pos(FFILE* file, const FSAVEPOS* pos); // pass by reference
```

What would you advise as the best idea?

Comment: Btw, it makes little sense to make value arguments `const`. It is possible, and makes them behave like constant variables inside the function, but it doesn't make the interface clearer. I advise against it.

Comment: Are you sure it's bad? I use const on pointers, especially, to indicate that they won't be changed. Arguably it doesn't make sense for scalars, but it shouldn't harm anything...

Comment: Smallest memory footprint would probably mean you'd have to pass a pointer to the struct, but you'd have to try it and see. Perhaps write a small test-program and look at what the compiler does (optimization-wise), it's possible that if you pass a struct, the compiler optimizes that to passing a pointer anyway

Comment: @MightyPork No I'm not "sure", this is not a hard rule. And I specifically said "value types" trying to exclude pointers, *of course* pointers must be `const` whenever possible since that is an important part of the public interface. For scalars, it's useless to the outside world which is why I think it should not be done.

Comment: @unwind `const char*` to indicate the you won't modify the data pointed to is good. `char * const` or `const int`, however,  is rather pointless for a parameter, as you point out.

Comment: @unwind So, does it sound better if I don't use `const` in the H-file for scalars, but use it in the C-file to help optimization? (though I'm not 100% sure the compiler needs it)

Comment: @unwind: `const` on pointer can be useful to make sure the pointer is not inadvertently changed. And the benefits of a pointer to a `const struct` are hopefully obvious: the object pointed to cannot be changed. Which makes this most times a good (and faster) alternative to passing a struct by copy. For scalars, I also do not see much sense (but might enforce a single-assignment policy.

Comment: the simplest answer is "just try it" what happens when you try these and look at the actual size of the binary, better, disassemble the functions in question (caller and callee) and see if they are putting the whole struct on the stack or not.  As Peter is pointing out if the size is similar to a pointer then it doesnt matter much but if the struct is of any (large) size and ram consumption, etc are a premium then just use a pointer

Comment: @dwelch: ARM AAPCS might pass small structs in a register. For larger structs as argument, this is most times a bad idea. For results, it does not make a difference actually if the result is only used by the caller (the struct is allocated on the stack either way with a pointer passed to the callee).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to minimise memory footprint, then a `struct` type that is significantly larger than a pointer is better passed using a pointer.   Data that is significantly smaller is better passed by value.    If a pointer and the data are about the same size, it doesn't matter much.

Assuming you are on AVR32, your pointer will be 32-bit and the struct is 64-bit (plus any padding).

That would suggest you are better passing by pointer/reference.   However, the struct is not particularly large, other considerations may dominate - there is not really a lot in it for your `struct` type, as it is not particularly large.   You would need to measure relevant quantities (memory usage, code size, speed, etc) to be sure.

So the best idea, I suggest, is to measure - these things are affected by host architecture, compiler settings, quality of implementation of the compiler, etc.

Although you haven't asked, larger types (like `uint32_t`) tend to have larger alignment requirements than smaller types (like `uint16_t`).    A consequence of this is a fairly common guideline of ordering members of your struct so larger types appear first in memory.   This is probably not significant in your case either (it is a fair bet that a 16 bit type will be aligned to 16 bit boundaries, and 32-bit types to 32-bit boundaries, so it is likely there will be no padding in your case).   However, if you had three `uint16_t` members rather than two, you would be better off ordering things so the `uint32_t` members are first.   In other words, instead of

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t a,b,c;
    uint32_t d;
} SOME_TYPE;
```

you would be better off using a different order.

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t d;
    uint16_t a,b,c;
} SOME_TYPE;
```

Comment: it's atmega328p, so I believe the pointer is actually 2-byte, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Whether or not  a `struct` is larger than the pointer type on the platform and alignment issues are NOT the only things that need to be considered here.  Passing a *pointer* into a function, particularly a globally scoped function (i.e. non-static) will force the data to be written to RAM.  Passing in a struct *may* allow the compiler to keep the entire struct in registers which would both reduce stack usage and speed up execution. This is particularly true on CPUs with a lot of registers and can be a cause of performance differences between pass-by-ref and pass-by-ptr in C++.

Comment: Also, I don't believe this applies on the atmega328, but the concern of registers vs stack usage is *especially* true on register-windowing architectures, e.g. SPARC, though I think this is increasingly uncommon in anything but "big iron" machines.

Comment: Passing a pointer does not force data to be written to RAM, except in very specific circumstances.   It prevents compiler/architecture specific optimisations such as passing struct members in registers.   But those members are more likely to be copied from RAM into the registers, rather than from other registers - and will still exist in RAM anyway. The main exceptions would be trivial programs that use only one instance of a particular struct type.  Few programs do that, and separate compilation models limit ability of compilers to detect such cases anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, when you return a struct in C, it's usually returned in a register if it fits or is implicitly passed by reference and modified AFAIK. So, in the best case it's better and in the worst case is equal than the second approach.

In the second case it depends on the size of a pointer and the size of the struct among other things. In this case is very difficult to say anything without measurement. It probably won't be much different with a struct of that size, though.

However you should consider also having consistency with the rest of your API, and having a system to notify errors if you can't do the operation (if the operation can fail).